# How to measure the displacement of a force over a sphere

Tags: forces, pressure, material-science, elasticity

I know it seems like a broad answer but since it is really straight forward to measure the displacement of a beam, how do you measure the displacement of a "steel" sphere when a force is placed over it? Assuming the sphere is a solid.

To illustrate:
[image]

I can use also some advice on what subjects to proceed and study to learn something like that so as to not take advantage... This is just for curiosity really.

The diameter and young modulus are just variables can be replaced by other amounts*

Comment: Just to clarify... I assume that there is an equal and opposite force pushing upwards on the bottom of the sphere, so that the sphere is being compressed in the vertical direction, and that you want to know by how much the vertical 'diameter' decreases.

Comment: Oh right! Forgot to add that sorry,

Comment: About subjects and material, well, if I understood your question correctly, maybe what you are looking for is [Contact Mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contact_mechanics).

Comment: thanks you very much! didn't know the name of that subject, I'll start digging @Physicist137

Comment: Actually, re-reading your question, well. Contact mechanics may be much more than what you are looking for. I guess you can approximate the problem to an usual elasticity problem. You can use spherical coordinates and simply to calculate the deformation tensor from applied stress using the elasticity equations, and then figure out the new shape of the sphere while the force is there. It is not hard to do this and there's no need for complicated contact mechanics this way.

Comment: Thanks again for clarifying @Physicist137 ! I study more of a technical career so this is a little beyond my scope so I'll look up how to get into that problem. I've heard of the elasticity equations before but in class they only taught us the double integral method and that stuff over beams... Thanks again!

Comment: You might be interested in [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/308841/what-is-the-stiffness-of-a-crushed-rod-or-cylinder/309585#309585) and the reference in there.